# Sending ARRAY to VALUES clause fails

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

If I want to construct a temporary valueset for testing, I can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES (97.99), (98.01), (99.00))
```

which will result in this:

|  | COLUMN1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 97.99 |
| 2 | 98.01 |
| 3 | 99.00 |

However, if I want to construct a result set where one of the columns contains an `ARRAY`,  like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES (97.99, [14, 37]), (98.01, []), (99.00, [14]))
```

I would expect this:

|  | COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 97.99 | [14, 37] |
| 2 | 98.01 | [] |
| 3 | 99.00 | [14] |

but I actually get the following error:

> Invalid expression [ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(14, 37)] in VALUES clause

I don't see anything in the documentation for the `VALUES` clause that explains why this is invalid. What am I doing wrong here and how can I generate a result set with an ARRAY column?

Comment: fyi, you don't need the outer brackets, `SELECT * FROM VALUES (97.99), (98.01), (99.00)` is equally valid, and touch more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the values clause only allows primitive types. You can define it as a string in single quotes and use parse_json to turn it into an array:

```
SELECT $1 COL1, parse_json($2)::array COL2 
FROM (VALUES (97.99, '[14, 37]'), (98.01, '[]'), (99.00, '[14]'));
```

Answer (score 2):

`VALUES()` has some restrictions:

> Each expression must be a constant, or an expression that can be evaluated as a constant during compilation of the SQL statement.
>
> Most simple arithmetic expressions and string functions can be evaluated at compile time, but most other expressions cannot.
>
> https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/values.html

Comment: For a solution, see Greg's answer. This answer meanwhile points to the docs on "why".

Answer (score 2):

From the [**documentation**](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/values.html)

> Each expression must be a constant, or an expression that can be
> evaluated as a constant during compilation of the SQL statement.
>
> Most simple arithmetic expressions and string functions can be
> evaluated at compile time, **but most other expressions cannot**.

The documentation doesn't explicitly says this, but given the ability of arrays to hold multiple data types and varying number of elements, I want to say arrays in most SQL based databases are dynamic arrays that don't evaluate at compile time. Maybe some experts can shed more light on this.

Back to your problem, I would just use explicit `select` statements like:

```
 select 97.99, [14, 37] union all
 select 98.01, [];
```